# importlib._bootstrap and python interpreter initialization

Tags: python, python-3.x, initialization, cpython

CPython interpreter modules import system is written in python itself and is initialized in `importlib._bootstrap`. Its source can be seen in `importlib/_bootstrap.py`, but it is not loaded from there. Instead it is loaded from so called frozen module, which bytecode is [baked](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/frozen.c#L31L45) into the interpreter library (`python37.dll`).

The interpreter initializes itself by [importing `_frozen_importlib` (it's a name for `importlib._bootstrap` baked into the interpreter)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pylifecycle.c#L186) and [calling `_install` function defined there, passing `sys` and `_imp` modules as arguments](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pylifecycle.c#L217). [`_install`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L1158) calls [`_setup`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L1123L1146), which initializes runtime needed for this module, and then adds 2 importers, implementing [PEP 451](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0451/).

When developing a custom importer I have encountered several bugs either in `_bootstrap.py` or in my importer, so I need to add some debug output into `_bootstrap.py`.

So I try to make the interpreter to load `_bootstrap.py` from disk, not from baked-in bytecode.

Analysis of cpython source code revealed that in order to import builtin modules I don't need the most of spec class. So builtin modules can be imported using `_create_builtin`

```py
class UltraSimpleSpec:
    __slots__=("name",)
    def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name

def _install(sys, _imp):
    io = _imp.create_builtin(UltraSimpleSpec("_io"))
    _bi = _imp.create_builtin(UltraSimpleSpec("builtins"))
    fd = io.open("path/to/_bootstrap.py", "rt") # exits the _install function without any exception, how can it do it?
    raise _bi.Exception("Never called") # _bi.print doesn't work, because sys.stdout is not initialized, so I have to use exceptions for debug output
    ...
```

Unfortunately something strange happens and call to io.open causes `_install` to exit, control flow never reaches the next statement. And no exception seems to be raised, when it is, interpreter prints it, instead an exception is raised in another place because of missing side effect of `_install`.

Yet ahother nuisance is that `sys.stdout` is not initialized, so we cannot `print` and have to rely on exceptions for debug output.

So

1. How should I make `open` work?
2. How should I initialize `sys.stdout`?

Comment: i would be curious to know about those bugs you encountered in "_bootstrap.py" even on platform as weird as wasm or android there's no need to modify it. What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: IDK for now (have not yet debugged it, was busy), but it breaks when interacts to my custom module loaders. 1 `importlib.reload` doesn't work. 2. When I load a module with [my custom loader, wrapping `importlib.import_module`](https://gitlab.com/KOLANICH/lazily.py), when I load later a submodule of that module, I get an error that the module is not present.

Comment: you may want to call importlib.invalidate_caches() before using reload or plugin systems.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer, but I have solved one issue only for my case (loading python source code).

> How should I make `open` work?

It turned out that string encodings are unavailable that time, so I used `rb` instead of `r`. Then I pass the `bytes` to `compile`, it can deal with them.

Comment: I think you may need to to ```import _bootlocale``` before hooking import system and/or use PYTHONUTF8=1 in startup environnement. There's a possibility of circular import with text iowrappers + getpreferredencoding. i think it's fixed in 3.10.  ( cf https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/locale.py#L658 )

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have looked into cpython source code and saw `_bootlocale` is imported through `PyImport_ImportModule`, which calls `PyImport_Import`, which calls `__import__`. So in normal operation import system must already be working by the time `_bootlocale` is imported.